# twitteroauth (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) returning empty array after get. Hostinger hosting

Tags: twitter, get, hosting, twitter-oauth

I have been coding some PHP to get some twits from twitter API using twitteroauth (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). I have been using my local apache server and running the code without any problems.

After, I uploaded the code to hostinger (PHP version 5.4), but when the code executes it returns an empty array in GET.

Code:

```
//Create the connection
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

//Verify credentials
$content = $twitter->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

With my local server $content has the right response (code 200, authenticated correctly). In hostinger (http://www.hostinger.es) $content is an empty array.

do you know something about this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have exact same problem, google brought me here, maybe hostinger is banned on twitter. It may be their utc time that is 3 min a head.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```